# Airport Extreme to 3 Sony Airplay speakers

Tags: audio, airport, airplay

I'm was wondering, before purchasing the [Airport Extreme](http://www.macworld.com/article/2033878/review-apples-airport-extreme-is-a-safe-choice.html) , if it was possible to connect my 3 [Sony Airplay speakers](https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=SANS310&LOC=3#/howtoTab)  to the 3 LAN Ports of the Airport Extreme and airplay simultaneously as multi-room audio from my Iphone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you connect multiple Sony Speakers?  Yes.  Why wouldn't you be able to?

The AirPort Extreme is just like any other WiFi router in as much it is a router, a switch, and a WAP (Wireless Access Point) like any other wireless router.

The Sony speakers are just like any other WiFi speakers in as much they are clients on a WiFi network.

**The real question here is does iOS support streaming to multiple AirPlay speakers simultaneously?**

Currently, [the answer is NO](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4965141?start=0&tstart=0).  This is a limitation of iOS.

However, there is an App called [Airfoil Satellite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airfoil-satellite/id1015554329?mt=8) which gets your around this limitation.